# Export selected PPT slides as a PDF attachment in outlook email

Tags: vba, outlook, powerpoint

See code below does work as a PPTX currently.

I need to have this export as a PDF not a PPTX and am having no luck. Help much appreciated! Also having no luck adding an email signature automatically to this code. Granted many users will end up using this macro.

```
Sub EmailFinal()

 Dim objActivePresetation As Presentation
    Dim objSlide As Slide
    Dim n As Long
    Dim strName As String
    Dim strTempPresetation As String
    Dim objTempPresetation As Presentation
    Dim objOutlookApp As Object
    Dim objMail As Object
 
    Set objActivePresetation = ActivePresentation
 
    For Each objSlide In objActivePresetation.Slides
        objSlide.Tags.Delete ("Selected")
    Next
 
    'Add a tag "Selected" to the selected slides
    For n = 1 To ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Count
        ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange(n).Tags.Add "Selected", "YES"
    Next n
 
    strName = objActivePresetation.Name
    strName = Left(strName, InStrRev(strName, ".") - 1)
    strTempPresetation = Environ("TEMP") & "\" & strName & ".pptx"
 
    'Copy the active presentation to a temp presentation
    objActivePresetation.SaveCopyAs strTempPresetation
    Set objTempPresetation = Presentations.Open(strTempPresetation)
 
    'Remove the untagged slides
    For n = objTempPresetation.Slides.Count To 1 Step -1
        If objTempPresetation.Slides(n).Tags("Selected") <> "YES" Then
           objTempPresetation.Slides(n).Delete
        End If
    Next n
 
    objTempPresetation.Save
    objTempPresetation.Close
 
    'Attach the temp presentation to a new email
    Set objOutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objMail = objOutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
 
    'Change the email details as per your needs
    With objMail
         .To = "insertemailhere"
         .Subject = strName
         .Body = "Dear Company," & vbCr & vbCr & "Please see attached Plaques.," & vbCr & "Please let me know if you need any further assistance."
         .Attachments.Add strTempPresetation
         .Display
    End With
End Sub
```

Thank You!!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentation.exportasfixedformat

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Presentation.ExportAsFixedFormat method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentation.exportasfixedformat).

Instead of `objTempPresetation.Save` do `objTempPresetation.ExportAsFixedFormat` and specify your desired parameters but at least specify those parameters:

```
objTempPresetation.ExportAsFixedFormat Path:="C:\yourpath\yourfile.pdf", FixedFormatType:=ppFixedFormatTypePDF
```

other parameters are optional.